# How to know what URL MVC.NET is trying to find

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My MVC4 application has a form. In this, people choose criteria from select boxes and then click search.

At this point, it directs to a controller, which stores the value as a `TempData` and then redirects to the correct landing page.

So, from the View, after the search button is clicked the path is Shoes in my ProductController

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Shoes(Shoe shoe)
    {

        TempData["shoe"] = shoe;

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Shoes", new  { SelectedSize = shoe.SelectedSize, SelectedColour = shoe.SelectedColour });

    }
```

The above redirects to

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(Shoes shoes, int startIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        //logic
    }
```

My 2 routes are

```
   routes.MapRoute(
      name: "ShoesA",
      url: "Shoes/{startIndex}",
      defaults: new { startIndex = 0, pageSize = 10, controller = "ShoesConnectors", action = "Index" }
      );

        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Everything works fine. The URL resolves to `http://localhost:52603/Shoes?SelectedSize=12`

What I want, is to change the URL to not use querystring. EG

`http://localhost:52603/Shoes?SelectedSize=12`

to become

`http://localhost:52603/Shoes/12`

(I should point out, I'm using pagination via the route, so it will actually show `http://localhost:52603/Shoes/10/12` where `10` is the startIndex)

So, I added the following routes

```
        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ShoesB",
        url: "Shoes/{startIndex}/{SelectedSize}/{SelectedColour}",
        defaults: new { startIndex = 0, pageSize = 10, controller = "Shoes", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ShoesC",
        url: "Shoes/{startIndex}/{SelectedSize}",
        defaults: new { startIndex = 0, pageSize = 10, controller = "Shoes", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ShoesD",
        url: "Shoes/{startIndex}/{SelectedColour}",
        defaults: new { startIndex = 0, pageSize = 10, controller = "Shoes", action = "Index" }
        );
```

When I click my search button, I am shown a 404 page

I understand that this error exists due due to the new routes but I don't understand why it can't find the page...

The URL resolves as expected, to `http://localhost:52603/Shoes/0/12` but, I don't know how to debug this.

Why can't MVC find the correct Controller? What is it trying to resolve to?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [Attribute Routing](http://attributerouting.net/)

**Edit**: by the way, if you are in a position to update to `MVC5`, attribute routing is "built in" (see [Attribute Routing in MVC5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, this is very easily done in MVC4. The examples I posted were pretty much correct.

The fault was within a setting in the project in Visual Studio. I opened up the project's Properites, and navigated to the Web tab.

From here, I un-chekced the "Use Local IIS Web server" and chose "Use Visual Studio Development Server" and this resolved the issue.